# How can I detect just AUTO_INCREMENTed value with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, auto-increment

#### Hello !

I'd like to know, what value have just assigned `A_I` method in my `MySQL` table. I can't look for it by specifying other values, because at least two of them could be the same. I'm really stuck.

Let's say I'm using this simple code to `INSERT` new `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (`Auto_Incremented_Value`, `My_Column`) VALUES (NULL, '$my_value');
```

Now I need to know what is the last value of `Auto_Incremented_Value` column, because I have to use this value in order to assign it to another table as a link to that object.

In real I allow some people to upload images on my server & these are associated with some products which they belong to. I have two tables to handle this.The first one (`products` table) uses `AUTO_INCREMENT` & the second one (`images` table)  doesn't, because I store there full path to the uploaded image, small description & link to the assigned product. I need to store the `Auto_Incremented_Value` as the link in my `images` table .

P.S. I'd be pleased if I could solve it with PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [MySQLI Insert ID](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id) for this.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO my_table (`Auto_Incremented_Value`, `My_Column`) VALUES (NULL, '$my_value')";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `mysqli` you can retrieve the auto-incremented value with `mysqli_insert_id()` immediately after you have executed your query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "Insert into someTable values (null, 'a','b','c')") or die(mysqli_error($link));

$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

For PDO you can do something similar and use PDO::lastInsertId to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PDO, you can get the new value like this:
`$nextAIValue = $pdo->lastInsertId();`
If you're using mySQLi, use this:
`$nextAIValue = mysqli_insert_id();`
If you're using plain `mysql_*` functions (which are deprecated, though), get the value like this:
`$nextAIValue = mysql_insert_id();`

Comment: Why suggest solutions for deprecated libraries/what about mysqli?

Comment: I've edited my answer. However, if you look at PHP questions here, you'll notice that a great number of developers still use `mysql_*`. Sad but true. So I decided to provide the OP with this solution, also, just in case.